# Redux Form unit test

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, chai, redux-form, enzyme

I tried to write unit test with enzyme to component that wrapped to redux-form w, I met a problem when try to test some component that renders depends on formValues HOC from redux-form HOC, how to test and simulate store or props from fromValues to component. Sure I have some parent element that wrapped to HOC redux-form

```
 export const MiConfiguration = ({miConfiguration, change}) =>
{
    miConfiguration.isMiEnabled = miConfiguration.miConfigurationType !== MiConfigurationTypes.AccessPointOnly

    return <FormSection name='miConfiguration'>
        <Field
            name='miConfigurationType'
            component={renderSelectField}
            label={<FormattedMessage id='passage.label.scenario' />}
            style={{width: 400, ...styles.selectField}}
            hintText={<FormattedMessage id='passage.selectConfiguration.hint'/>}
            autoWidth
            onChange={(e, newValue) => Object.keys(defaultValues[newValue]).forEach(key => change(key, defaultValues[newValue][key]))}
        >
        {miConfiguration && !!miConfiguration.miConfigurationType &&
            <InfoMessage id={`miConfiguration.description.${miConfiguration.miConfigurationType}`} />}

    </FormSection>}
```

Unit Test

```
describe('getMiConfiguration', () => {
    let component, onChange

    beforeEach(() => {
        component = shallow(<MiConfiguration miConfiguration={{}} change={onChange = sinon.spy()}/>)
    })

    it('should render <InfoMessage /> with id', () =>{
        component.setProps({miConfiguration: {miConfigurationType: 'type'})
component.find(InfoMessage).props().id.should.be.equal('some id')
        component.find(InfoMessage).should.exist})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;[{id: MiConfigurationTypes.AccessPointOnly},
        {id: MiConfigurationTypes.WanderingDetection},
        {id: MiConfigurationTypes.MuteWanderingDetection},
        {id: MiConfigurationTypes.LockedWanderingControl},
        {id: MiConfigurationTypes.OpenWanderingControl},
    ].forEach(({id}) => {
        it(`should render correct <InfoMessage/> with ${id} for each MI configuration scenarios id`, () => {
            component.setProps({miConfiguration: {miConfigurationType: id}})

            component.find(InfoMessage).findWhere(x => x.props().id === `miConfiguration.description.${id}`).should.exist
        })
    })
```